# Solving summations by upper bound - lower bound + 1

Tags: summation, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

I’ve seen many different summations that are solved by the upper bound minus the lower bound plus one.

For example:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} {1} = n-1+1
$$

May I always resolve summations in this way or are there any exceptions/restrictions?

Comment: $$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} {2} \neq n-1+1
$$
Where else did you see it in this context? Your equation doesn't apply in the general case at all, but maybe if you showed another example or two we could understand what you may be thinking.

Comment: Maybe $\sum_{i=1}^{n} {2} = {2 \cdot n-1+1}$ ?

Comment: $$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} {i} = 1 + 2 + ... + n = \frac{n^2+n}{2} \neq n-1+1
$$

If the body of the summation is complicated then it probably won't match your assumption.

Comment: Is the body of your summation always constant with respect to $n$ and $i$?